# Application-wide designer initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-designer

Currently I am using static constructor **for each** Window/UserControl to perform some initialization, which is the **same** for all of them (initializing static property of some external library class, required for markup extensions located in this library to work).

Is there an application-wide place to perform that initialization? E.g. something what is executed by designer before rendering window xaml in designer?

In run-time all initialization occurs in `App` constructor. And it's weird cloning dozens of static constructors just for designer, because designer seems don't care about `App`.

I'd make a base class with such static constructor for all Windows/UserControls, unfortunately c# doesn't support multi-inheritance.

Comment: Annoyingly static constructors [aren't reliable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34672949/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use singleton pattern instead of static constructor?

e.g. in ViewModel: `var yourComponent = YourComponent.Current;`

```
public class YourComponent
{
   private static YourComponent _current;
   public static YourComponent Current { 
     get {
        return _current ?? (_current = new YourComponent());
     }
   }

   private YourComponent()
   {
      //perform your initialization here. This will be executed only once;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To answer your question, whether there is global initialization place for wpf (xaml) designer: yes, it is - app.xaml

Although xaml designer does not trigger the app events in codebehind, it loads resources, and you can easily intantiace any class in resources. Just perform your initialization logic in constuctor of the class and add the class to app resources

Comment: This lead me to idea to have base class for `Windows` and another one for `UserControl`, that is just 2 static constructors . Not really sure why singleton. Still question is open, I'd really like to know if such global initialization place for wpf (xaml) designer exists.

Comment: avoid using static constructor. If an error occurs in static constructor (and there can be always some unexpected exception), than it will fail in unpredictable places, because you never know when static costructor will be invoked