# WPF designer doesn't run window static constructor upon starting up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-designer

When I load solution and there is an opened designer tab for some window, then this window static constructor is not executed.

Perhaps my conclusion is wrong (because I am absolutely clueless how designer load things), but here is a test case:

1. Create new WPF project.
2. Create simple extension

```
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public static bool Test;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Test.ToString();
}
```

3. Add to main window

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:My}" />
```

and

```
static MainWindow()
{
    MyExtension.Test = true;
}
```

4. Now compile it (<kbd>F6</kbd>), `TextBlock` should show `True` in designer.
5. Do not close designer window. Close VS.
6. Start solution (double-click `sln` file).
7. As soon as designer loads window you will see `TextBlock` display `False`.

WTF? Can someone confirm that (or is it my VS 2015 bug)?

I would really like to know how designer works: how window is loaded, which events/methods are used, etc. It seems window constructor (non-static one) is not executed (anything put there is not happening in design time), how is the window then created and displayed?

Comment: What is "My"?, if "My" is a static field then your binding is wrong, it should be something like this <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:My}" />

Comment: @adminSoftDK, it's not a binding, but a [markup extension](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight): `MyExtension` (word "Extension" is omitted when using extension in the xaml, similar to attributes).

Comment: Why don't you set `MyExtension.Test = true` in the `App` constructor instead?

Comment: @MikeEason, `App` is not used when window is rendered in the designer. It would work during run-time, but I am interested in both: design-time and run-time, therefore I tried to use static constructor... which doesn't work in design time upon VS startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know how it works for Visual Studio 2010 and reading your question I *suppose* that the same principles may be also applied to Visual Studio 2015.

When a control is rendered inside the XAML designer (regarding VS2010 it is called **Cider** ) as the main control (i.e. a `Window`) its constructor is not run. On the other side, if a control is a child of another control which is rendered inside the XAML designer, the first control's constructor is executed (i.e. a `UserControl` inside a `Window`). You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2007/11/08/code-behind-and-the-wpf-designer.aspx).

So you need to move the `My.Test` initialization into a customized control, for example:

```
public class MyTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    static MyTextBlock()
    {
        MyExtension.Test = true;
    }
}
```

Then use it inside your `Window`:

```
<local:MyTextBlock Text="{local:My}" />
```

After you compile your project, you will see the "True" text in the designer. I repeat: it works for Visual Studio 2010, so I hope it can represent an hint to solve your issue.

Comment: Even if it works idea with subclassing every control doesn't sounds very appealing. Or do you mean to create just one *fake* `UserControl` (or custom control?) to run custom code for **window** (containing that control)?

Comment: @Sinatr, since we are talking about a static constructor, I mean _just one_ "fake" extended control. Its purpose is just to initialize your extensions' values (like `MyExtension`). So each `Window` needs to contain just one instance of our "fake" control.

Comment: You are right @Sinatr, I agree: it is a sad workaround. But since the designer works in that way, I guess there are not so many other solutions.

Comment: I had a brilliant idea to move initialization into attached property (e.g. setting attached property for window).. to find out what attached property is set **after** markup extensions...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you last comment. Now I see your solution does not work